# Why my identity column value starts at 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server to create a table and insert data for it, but why does an open id not 1 but 2?

```
create table test1
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(255),
    age int,
    primary key (id),
    constraint check_age check (age > 0 and age <= 150)
);
```

The following is the result of the display.

```
select * from test1;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------+-----+
| id |     name     | age |
+----+--------------+-----+
|  2 | shenmeshenqi |  20 |
|  3 | shenmeshenq  |  21 |
+----+--------------+-----+
```

Who can help me? Thank you

Comment: Did u delete any record from that table?

Comment: @PawanKumar    I did not delete the data in the table. But I just rebuilt a table and found 1, I think the problem seems to be solved, but in my table I also use `dbcc checkident (test1, reseed, 0); ` statement to reset ID. but the first show is still 2..

Comment: This happen when you delete any row from the table AI(Auto increments) continue.. if you want to reset that and start from 1 you should TRUNCATE table but take care TRUNCATE will delete all rows in your table

Comment: @SiderTopalov Oh, my God. I seem to have executed this statement.`insert into test1 (name, age) values ('shenmeshenqi','500'); '. But its age is limited between 0 and 150. So the execution is a failure. I don't know if it will affect it.

Comment: Yes, that will pick up an incremented value for identity and then try and insert data. If it fails, then during next run the value being picked is auto incremented from the last value irrespective of success or failure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
--store values from the table in temporary table
select * into #tempTable from test1
--remove all records from the table
delete test1
--reset identity to start from 1
dbcc checkident (test1, reseed, 0);
--insert data back to the table, now the records will be numbered starting with 1
insert into test1
select * from #tempTable
```

Comment: @什么神奇 Accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Pls, encourage the person by accepting his/her answer if it solved your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The below command will make the next insertion have the identity value as 1 and after that 2 and so on, thus 2 and 3 will be duplicates. You may want to just truncate the table for now as it looks like a test table.

```
dbcc checkident (test1, reseed, 0);
```

Also, you can turn onidentity insert, then insert data with value 1 as id and then turn off the identity again, if required.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Test1 ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Test1 OFF
```

Hope it helps.